# How to start and stop a Sinatra application using Thin on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, sinatra, thin

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  def hello
    "world"
  end
end
```

From documentation I found that I can start the application like this:

```
App.run
```

Although this does not return the control.

How do I start the application in the background and how can I then stop it.

My environment is: Windows, Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: what do mean by return control? like at the command prompt? Also, the code you have is nowhere near being able to work

Comment: Does thin even work on Windows?

Answer (score 7):

Use a config.ru file like Dmitry Maksimov suggested:

```
#config.ru
require './your_app_file'

run YourApp
```

And then start with `rackup -D` which means deamonize and therefore it runs in the background.

I wouldn't recommend this for development though. Better have a look at [Shotgun](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun)

Comment: How do you stop it after its been deamonize?

Comment: http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/usage/
I can't check right now. But a combination of `thin start -C ...` with a config file and deamonizing should give you the possibility to stop it with something like `thin stop -C ...`

Answer (score 6):

Create in the top directory of your application rackup file - config.ru - with the following content:

```
# config.ru
$: << File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

require 'your app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Then just run your app with the `thin start`

Comment: thin start seems to hold control, it does not seem to run in the background.